# How to get particular controller scope list in console - angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, browser, console

I am trying to edit bus list in browser console for this bus search angualrjs site.

I tried to access the `filteredBusData`(ng-repeat) list in that page which is used in ng-repeat from console.

#### Code:

**Method 1:**

```
angular.element(document.body).injector().invoke(function ($rootScope)
{
        scope = $rootScope;
        console.log(scope.filteredBusData);
});
```

**Method 2:**

```
angular.element('[ng-controller="busTicketCheckoutCtrl"]').scope;

`busTicketCheckoutCtrl` is the particular controller
```

#### Problem:

Both the `methods` didn't work :(

Method 1: `scope.filteredBusData` is undefined

Method 2: Uncaught Error: [jqLite:nosel] Looking up elements via selectors is not supported by jqLite!

#### Question:

How to access the particular controller scope in the browser console?

Any suggestion/idea will be grateful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@jonnyknowsbest Answer is correct but the main thing is site has disabled debug info, you need to first enable it using `angular.reloadWithDebugInfo()`  this command will reload you page. After that you can access to controller object.

And then you could do access angular scope in you console.

```
angular.element(document.querySelector('[data-ng-controller=busTicketCheckoutCtrl]')).scope()
```

Comment: @jonnyknowsbest your solution was right just modified it.. Thanks :)

Comment: Any idea to use  `angular.reloadWithDebugInfo()` in casperjs.

Comment: @karthick.k no bro..I don't have idea about casper.js.but it should be as same as this.just you need to make sure page has loaded .. **NOTE** please bro don't paste your site URL dirctly here that can harm you in any way..Thanks

Comment: @karthick.k Glad to assist you..Thanks you so much :)

Answer (score 2):

```
var scope = angular.element($('[ng-controller=busTicketCheckoutCtrl]')).scope();
```

If you're not using jQuery, then you want:

```
var scope = angular.element(document.querySelector('[ng-controller=busTicketCheckoutCtrl]')).scope();
```

At the moment you are just passing a string into angular.element() and i think it wants an actual element.

Comment: change it to `angular.element(document.querySelector('[data-ng-controller=busTicketCheckoutCtrl]'))` but still not able to access scope using `angular.element(document.querySelector('[data-ng-controller=busTicketCheckoutCtrl]')).scope()`

Comment: Thanks for the info. It is given `undefined`